# Change size of all text areas at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a function that increases the height of a text area when a user clicks inside the text area. It increases so the user can view all the contents inside the text area. It works fine currently. But I only managed to make it work one text area at a time. I'd like to change it so that ALL text areas increase at the same time whenever one of them is clicked. If anyone can give me an idea I would appreciate it.

**Current HTML**

```
<textarea name="xaxis1" id="xaxis1_id" rows="3" cols="20">report
facture
credit
impot</textarea>

<textarea name="yaxis1" id="yaxis1_id" rows="3" cols="20">200
123
231
431</textarea>

<textarea name="yaxis2" id="yaxis2_id" rows="3" cols="20">431
111
666
991</textarea>
```

**Current JavaScript Code**

```
$('#xaxis1_id').click(function()  {   
    resizeTextArea($('#xaxis1_id'));
});             
$('#yaxis1_id').keydown(function(e) {
    resizeTextArea($('#yaxis1_id'));
});        
$('#yaxis2_id').click(function()  {   
    resizeTextArea($('#yaxis2_id'));
});

function resizeTextArea(currentTextArea)  {
  var textAreaElements = currentTextArea.val().split('\n');

  var b=1;
  var totalColumns = currentTextArea.attr('cols');

  for (x=0;x < textAreaElements.length; x++)   {
     if (textAreaElements[x].length >= totalColumns) 
        b+= Math.floor(textAreaElements[x].length/totalColumns);
  }

  b+= textAreaElements.length;

  var totalRows = currentTextArea.attr('rows');
  currentTextArea.attr('rows', b);
}
```

Comment: Just use a jQuery class selector instead of Id selector.  Then pass $(this) to the resizeTextArea function

Comment: `function resizeTextArea(currentTextArea)` is receiving only one `textarea` object.It's not getting any `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them all to expand whenever any of them is clicked this will work:

[View Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hVRRF/8/)

```
$('textarea').click(function()  {   
  $('textarea').each(function() {
      resizeTextArea($(this));
  });
});
```

Update:
Per question below, to have this fire on click and keydown you can do this:

```
$('textarea').on("click keydown", function()  {
  $('textarea').each(function() {
    resizeTextArea($(this));
  });
});
```

Update 2: To call this on a "paste" event, add a setTimeout call:

```
$('textarea').on("click keydown paste", function()  {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('textarea').each(function() {
      resizeTextArea($(this));
    });
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Works well but how do you make it so that the text area also increases when the enter key is hit(my old code currently does this).

I tried by adding the above code twice and only changing the "keydown", that worked but i'm not sure if there is a cleaner better way.

Comment: @camilos - See the update above.  You can do this using on("click keydown", function() ...

Comment: Thanks for all your help. One last question, how would I go about adding the same functionality when pasting data? In my old code, I would paste large amounts of rows and it would automatically resize. Now, it only resizes after I click inside the textarea. Or if i click on other textareas. 

I tried 
on("click keydown paste"   

but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the "paste" event fires before the text is actually pasted in.  A trick I've seen in other SO posts is to add a setTimeout before calling the resizeTextArea function.  I'll update the fiddle and the post with an example

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "textarea" ).bind( "click keydown", function() {
   resizeTextArea($this);
});
```

Comment: Also, this will only expand one of the text areas.  I believe the OP is asking that they all be expanded when any one of them is clicked: "I'd like to change it so that ALL text areas increase at the same time whenever one of them is clicked"

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. I just showed the direction for OP )) I believe that now he can handle its ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with this piece of code:

```
$("textarea").on("click keyup", function(event){
    resizeTextArea($(this));
});
```

Note that the parameter of the `resizeTextArea` function is a jQuery object not just a DOM object.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below in **document.ready** function and you can add different events - *click, keydown, etc*.

```
$( "textarea" ).bind( "click", function() {
    $( "textarea" ).each(function( index ) {
            var currentTextArea = $( this );
            var textAreaElements = currentTextArea.val().split('\n');

            var b = 1;
            var totalColumns = currentTextArea.attr('cols');

            for (x = 0; x < textAreaElements.length; x++) {
                if (textAreaElements[x].length >= totalColumns)
                    b += Math.floor(textAreaElements[x].length / totalColumns);
            }

            b += textAreaElements.length;

            var totalRows = currentTextArea.attr('rows');
            currentTextArea.attr('rows', b);
        });
    });
```